Error with data battles in assembler NASMx64 when writing data
The program is supposed to construct and display a binary tree with user-inputted data, and it should also allow searching and deleting elements. However, during compilation, an error occurs: "invalid combination of opcode and operands" on lines 128 and 131. This error is caused by writing 8 bits into 16 bits and vice versa.  All attempts to fix this issue have resulted in the program completely ceasing to function.
%include "io.inc"
section .data
array: dw 0x0812
section .text
global main
main:
  
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    xor eax, eax
    xor esi, esi
 
    call init
    mov eax, 19
    call addElem
    call showTree
    call searchElem
    mov eax, 19
    call removeElem
    call showTree
    mov eax, 10     
    call searchElem
    GET_HEX 2, ax
    PRINT_DEC 2, ax
    ret
    
init:
    mov al, 8
    call addElem
    mov al, 3
    call addElem
    mov al, 10
    call addElem 
    ret
    
addElem:
    ;push edx
    ;push ebp
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    test bx, bx
    jz null
    cmp bh, al
    je equal
    jg goRight
    jmp goLeft 
    null:
    mov ah, al
    xor al, al
    ;pop ebp
    ;pop edx
    ret
    equal:
    ;pop ebp
    ;pop edx
    ret
    goRight:
    and bl, 0x3 ; b11
    cmp bl, 0
    je createRight
    movzx esi, bl
    call addElem
    ;pop ebp
    ;pop edx
    ret
createRight:

    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    inc esi
    mov [array + esi*2], ax  
    and bl, 0x3          
    inc bl               
    mov bh, bl             
    mov [array + esi*2 - 2], bx 
    
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    mov bh, al
    mov [array + esi*2], bx
    
    ;pop ebp
    ;pop edx
    ret
    
    goLeft:
    shr bl, 2
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je createLeft
    movzx esi, bl
    call addElem
    ret
createLeft:
    ;создаем элемент
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    inc esi
    mov [array + esi *2], ax  
    shr bl, 2              
    and bl, 0x3             
    inc bl                 
    mov bh, bl             
    mov [array + esi*2 - 2], bx  
     mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    mov bh, al
    mov [array + esi*2], bx
    
    ;pop ebp
    ;pop edx
    ret
removeElem:
    mov esi, 0
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    test bx, bx
    jz notFound_removeElem
    cmp bh, al
    je removeCurrent
    jg searchRight_removeElem
    jmp searchLeft_removeElem
notFound_removeElem:
    ret
removeCurrent:
  
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    shr bl, 2
    and bl, 0x3 ; b11
    movzx esi, bl
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    mov ax, bh ; ax = ID элемента
    
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    mov bh, ax
    mov [array + esi*2], bx
  
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    xor bh, bh
    mov [array + esi*2], bx
    ret
searchRight_removeElem:
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je notFound_removeElem
    movzx esi, bl
    call removeElem
    ret
searchLeft_removeElem:
    shr bl, 2
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je notFound_removeElem
    movzx esi, bl
    call removeElem
    ret
 
showTree:
    mov esi, 0
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    test bx, bx
    jz end_showTree
    push esi
    call showTree
    pop esi
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    PRINT_CHAR bh         ; Print the ID as a character
    PRINT_STRING " "       ; Print a space (using PRINT_STRING)
    ;mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je checkLeft
    push esi
    movzx esi, bl
    call showTree
    pop esi
checkLeft:
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    shr bl, 2
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je end_showTree
    push esi
    movzx esi, bl
    call showTree
    pop esi
end_showTree:
    ret
 
searchElem:
    mov esi, 0
    mov bx, [array + esi*2]
    test bx, bx
    jz notFound_searchElem
    cmp bh, al
    je found_searchElem
    jg searchRight_searchElem
    jmp searchLeft_searchElem
notFound_searchElem:
    ret
found_searchElem:
    ret
searchRight_searchElem:
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je notFound_searchElem
    movzx esi, bl
    call searchElem
    ret
searchLeft_searchElem:
    shr bl, 2
    and bl, 0x3
    cmp bl, 0
    je notFound_searchElem
    movzx esi, bl
    call searchElem
    ret

The task is: Write a program that works with binary trees. The program has arbitrary input data at the startup stage. The number of initial elements is at least 4. Also, write an additional method that outputs a sorted tree from smaller to larger (using the bubble method or based on the rules of tree construction).

You can't move 8-bit register to 16-bit register mov ax, bh and 16-bit to 8-bit mov bh, ax. In first case try movzx ax, bh (MOVZX r16, r/m8) in second case use 16-bit register as destination operand. bx is already in use so try other 16-bit register.
